# I have sold stock PUT option with strike 32,5 and expiration date JAN 2023. Stock will be acquired fully in cash for 32,25 in Q12023

Tags: put-options

What will happen with my PUT option if acquisition will happen before my put option expires?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to options if a company is acquired / bought out?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/10277/what-happens-to-options-if-a-company-is-acquired-bought-out)

Comment: Also relevant: [What happens to a PUT contract for a company that is sold above the strike price and before expiration?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/99732/what-happens-to-a-put-contract-for-a-company-that-is-sold-above-the-strike-price)