# In which case(s) can one receive Restricted Stock Units (RSUs) before they vest?

Tags: united-states, rsu

I read on https://www.schwab.com/public/eac/resources/articles/rsu_facts.html (the page is configured not be mirrored):

> With RSUs, you are taxed when the shares are delivered, which is almost always at vesting.

In which case(s) can one receive Restricted Stock Units (RSUs) before they vest?

Comment: Related question mentioning at least one possible case: [What typically happens to unvested stock during an acquisition?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/what-typically-happens-to-unvested-stock-during-an-acquisition)

Comment: A more likely scenario is if for some reason the stock can't be delivered to you until some time after the vesting date.